# Read/parse mail.log to make easier debugging

Tags: email, debian

I need to go through the mail.log and filter out a few emails that have been causing problems and wondered if there is anyway to make my life easier.

Is there anyway to parse the mail.log to make it easier to read (maybe displayed in a HTML table with sort capabilities) and filter emails from the log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also see http://code.google.com/p/logstash/ and http://loggly.com.

loggly is a commercial product much like splunk. logstash is a free/open source project.

Answer (score 0):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) is probably your best bet here.  It's free up to 500MB/day.